# Issue in fetching the output from local fs via StreamSet tool

Tags: streamsets

I am Exploring StreamSet Tool,I have a log file n , I need to parse the log file to the StreamSet tool,I passed the log file from the Directory to the  log parser,the format of the log parser is the Common log format , n the destination is the local fs..When I start executing it is running but I am not getting the output.Could any one please help me..

Comment: Did you try resetting the origin? Do you see anything in preview?

Comment: Also, asking in the StreamSets group is probably a good idea: https://groups.google.com/a/streamsets.com/forum/#!forum/sdc-user

Comment: Fine.. Thank you..